# Problemas con combo box anidado

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, mysql

Tengo un combobox anidado a otro combobox y funciona solo en la primera linea; resulta ser que quiero que el combobox me funciones en las otras filas (De abajo) que son el resultado de una petición a la base de datos, espero haberme explicado, abajo un fragmento del código:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#noap").change(function () {
           $("#noap option:selected").each(function () {
            elegido3=$(this).val();
            $.post("caso2.php", { elegido3: elegido3 }, function(data){
            $("#noap2").html(data);

            });            
        });
   })
});


</script>
```

Y el código html y php aquí:

```
  <?php //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          $res = mysqli_query($connex, $ret);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
          {?>



          <tr id="status" name="status">
            <td><form  method="post" autocomplete="off" class="para_envio" onsubmit="return false" >
             <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]"  size="10" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" readonly /><input type="hidden" name="bl3[]"  size="10" value="<?php echo $row['bl3']?>" readonly />
              <td><input type="text" name="cod_it[]"  size="10" value="<?php echo $row['cod_it']?>" readonly /></td>


             <td><input type="text" name="noap2[]"  size="5" value="<?php echo $row['noap2']?>" /></td>


             <td><input type="text" name="uni_ca[]"  size="5" value="<?php echo $row['uni_ca']?>" readonly/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="pla_ca[]" size="5" value="<?php echo $row['pla_ca']?>" readonly /></td>
             <td><input type="text" name="num_int[]"  size="5" value="<?php echo $row['num_int']?>" readonly/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="tipo_pa[]" size="8" value="<?php echo $row['tipo_pa']?>" readonly /></td>

              <td><select name="noap" id="noap" >  
                <option value="<?php echo  $row['noap'];?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row['noap'];?> </option>  
                <?php
                $sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM conductor ORDER BY nomapell';
            $result3 = mysqli_query($connex, $sql3);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {

            while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {


?>
                <option value="<?php echo  $row3['nomapell']; ?>" > <?php echo  $row3['nomapell']; ?>  </option>
                <?php  
       }
            }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de tu ejemplo primero debes cargar tu primero select o combobox unas vez el usuario selecciona una opcion mandar a buscar esa seleccion y cargar el segundo select y asi sucesivamente  ejemplo:

**alli seleccionas el estado**

```
    <div>Selecciona Estado : <select name="cbx_estado" id="cbx_estado">
        <option value="0">Seleccionar Estado</option>
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_estado']; ?>"><?php echo $row['estado']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select></div>
```

**con esto verificamos y obtenemos el valor del select y cargamos un nuevo combobox en base a la seleccion**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_estado").change(function () {

                $("#cbx_estado option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_estado = $(this).val();
                    $.post("getMunicipio.php", { id_estado: id_estado }, function(data){
                        $("#cbx_municipio").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });
```

**aqui se asigna el nuevo combobox**

```
<div>Selecciona Municipio : <select name="cbx_municipio" id="cbx_municipio"></select></div>
```

espero haberte ayudado !!

Comment: Eso lo se Diego, a lo que me refiero es que, si tengo multiples lineas de una consulta ejmplo:
conductor    código de conductor    carga
diego                 123                            h
carlos                 443                            b
pedro                  2323                         j

en el combo box quiero cambiar a carlos por otro conductor, en el select, selecciono el nombre y me debe cargar el código del conductor, y así en las demás lineas si quiero cambiarlo